# Set serializer field from data value having different names (Custom field Mapping for ModelSerizer)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Request model and follows

```
class TruRouteRequest(models.Model):
    msisdn = models.CharField('Subscriber international MSISDN ', max_length=25)
    sessionid = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    msg_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    msg = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I failed to write the name of the model field as '`type`' so i wrote '`msg_type`'. I have a ModelSerializer for the above model.
Data I am receiving have field 'type' which is required. How do I map `type` from serializer data to `msg_type` to avoid this error when calling is valid

```
>> serializer = TruRouteRequestSerializer(data=request.data)
>> serializer.data 
>> {'msisdn': 'M', 'sessionid': 'S', 'msg': 'MSG'}
>> request.data
>> {'msisdn': 'M', 'type': 'T', 'sessionid': 'S', 'msg': 'MSG'} # there is type
>> serializer.is_valid()
>> False
>> serializer.errors
>> {'msg_type': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly define `type` field inside serializer, and use `source` argument to map it to `msg_type` field:

```
class TruRouteRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.CharField(source='msg_type')

    class Meta:
        model = TruRouteRequest
        fields = ['type', ...]
```

Comment: Is it recommended to use python keyword as field name?

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali Do you mean `type` variable name? It's not recommended because you override builtin function in your class. But since you are not using in your code buildin `type` function, it's ok.